# Do I need to define a fixed width for each column or it can be automatically calculated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am wondering if there is any configuration and I am missing it where the columns fits the grid width automatically in jQgrid or if I need to define a fixed width (which is no so cool) for each of them. I have tried the following without success:

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var $grid = $("#list");

    $grid.jqGrid({
        url: '/ajax/plans_to_forms/get_all',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ["Actions", "Form #", "Form", "Plan", "Class", "Drug"],
        colModel: [
            {name: "act", template: "actions"},
            {name: "FormId", align: 'center', fixed: true, frozen: true, resizable: false, width: 50},
            {name: "FormName"},
            {name: "PlanName"},
            {name: "DrugGroupName"},
            {name: "DrugName"}
        ],
        cmTemplate: {autoResizable: true, editable: true},
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        rowNum: 25,
        guiStyle: "bootstrap",
        autoResizing: {compact: true},
        rowList: [25, 50, 100, "10000:All"],
        viewrecords: true,
        autoencode: true,
        sortable: true,
        pager: true,
        toppager: true,
        hoverrows: true,
        multiselect: true,
        multiPageSelection: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        sortname: "Id",
        sortorder: "desc",
        loadonce: true,
        autowidth: true,
        shrinkToFit: false
    }).jqGrid("navGrid", {
        edit: false,
        add: false,
        del: true,
        search: false,
        refresh: true
    }).jqGrid("filterToolbar").jqGrid("gridResize");
});
```

The result looks like:

[image]

Comment: I highly recommend you to read about [shrinkToFit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options&s[]=shrinktofit) option. Not sure if this stay in free-jqGrid, but in Guriddo jqGrid it is as described

Comment: @TonyTomov I already found the answer by setting `autowidth: true` makes the trick, thanks anyway

Comment: @ReynierPM: please add `javascript` or `jquery` tag to your question to make more colors in the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free jqGrid has the feature starting with the first released version (4.8). I described the feature in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Auto-adjustment-of-the-width-of-column). You need mostly to add `autoresizeOnLoad: true` option to the grid to solve your problem.

The problem is that there are exist many small interpretation of "auto-resizing" behavior. You can call `autoResizeAllColumns` method inside of `jqGridAfterLoadComplete` event to implement some variation of the standard behavior. For example [the answer](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/377#issuecomment-332121914) and the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dk2qwbcs/6/) shows how to use "auto-resizing" to reduce the grid size to the minimal width without shrink and to add horizontal scrollbar in the grid in case of small outer window.

Another property: `resetWidthOrg: true` of `autoResizing` option can be helpful in case of usage shinking. See the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ejpn9/149/ where the properties

```
autoresizeOnLoad: true,
autowidth: true,
autoResizing: {
    compact: true,
    resetWidthOrg: true
},
```

are used.

Comment: You're the best :)

Comment: What about "responsiveness"? If I resize the browser the grid does not resize so I am missing something here or is just not possible.

Comment: @ReynierPM: One need just register `resize` event on `window` where you call `setGridWidth`. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ejpn9/149/, which I included in my answer. It uses `$(window).on("resize", maximizeGrid);` where `maximizeGrid = function() { var newWidth = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width(); $grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);`